# Test for "not equal" on array using Controller.where() possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to use the '.where()' controller method to select all db-elements that are **not equal** to an array consisting of ID numbers?

I can easily use the '.where()' controller method to select all db elements that are equal to a list of ID numbers stored in an array:

```
user_event_ids = current_user.event_items.pluck(:event_id)

@user_events = Event.where(id: user_match_ids)
```

But I can't seem to find a way to select all db-elements that have ID numbers which ar enot in the 'user_event_ids' array.

I've tried (with no luck):

```
@non_user_events = Event.where('user_id not in :arr', {arr: user_event_ids})

@non_user_events = Event.where(''user_id != ?', user_event_ids)
```

Both do not work and cancel with errors. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `excluded_ids` is an Array containing the IDs you want to exclude

If you are using Rails 4:

```
Event.where.not(user_id: excluded_ids)
```

If you are using Rails 3:

```
Event.where('user_id NOT IN (?)', user_event_ids)
```

If you are using [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)

```
Event.where{user_id.not_in excluded_ids}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the detailed information. Now I understand why the 'Event.where.not(user_id: excluded_ids)' did not work for me, as I am still using Rails 3. I now used the second options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct syntax for what you are after:

```
Event.where('user_id NOT IN (?)', user_event_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another syntax:

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['user_id not in (?)', user_event_ids])
```